# Linux cp Permission denied on ntfs file system

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, ntfs

Could someone kindly explain why I get this Permission Denied error?  I personally am user `g` and as ls shows I have read and write permission for both source and destination.  My system is ***slackware 14***, and the device being written to is my ereader, an `ntfs-3g file system`.

I have other ntfs file systems, thumb drives, external HDDs etc to which I can write to as user.  There is no perceptible difference in the permissions setup for any of them.  Being ntfs, all of them are owned by root of group root.  It is only with this ereader that I have this problem (though I can write to it as root).  So I believe the problem is specific to this device, but I have no clue what it might be.

```
~ $ cp /home/g/MyBooks/Wyndham-TheMidwichCuckoos.txt /500gb/database/media/  
cp: cannot create regular file '/500gb/database/media/Wyndham-TheMidwichCuckoos.txt': Permission denied  
~ $ ls -l /home/g/MyBooks/Wyndham-TheMidwichCuckoos.txt                         
-rw-r--r-- 1 g users 380183 Aug 10 11:04 /home/g/MyBooks/Wyndham-TheMidwichCuckoos.txt  
~ $ ls -l /500gb/database/  
total 32  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug 10 11:23 cache/  
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 8192 Aug  5 13:26 layout/  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug  9 14:07 media/  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug  5 17:28 sync/  
~ $
```

The ereader is fat32, I had assumed it to be ntfs,
 ~ $ mount
/dev/sda3 on / type ext2 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
/dev/sda4 on /home type ext2 (rw)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /winxp type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)
/dev/sdb on /500gb type vfat (rw)
/dev/sdd1 on /3tb type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)
~ $ cp /home/g/MyBooks/Wyndham-TheMidwichCuckoos.txt /3tb
~ $ cp /home/g/MyBooks/Wyndham-TheMidwichCuckoos.txt /500gb
cp: cannot create regular file '/500gb/Wyndham-TheMidwichCuckoos.txt': Permission denied
~ $

I am not able to change the permissions on this ereader, neither as root, nor as user
As root, it appears to work, but nothing changes
/home/g # chmod 777 -R /500gb/database
/home/g # ls -l /500gb/database
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug 10 11:23 cache
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 8192 Aug  5 13:26 layout
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug  9 14:07 media
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug  5 17:28 sync

As user, the chmod is rejected thus
~ $ chmod 777 -R /500gb/database
chmod: changing permissions of '/500gb/database': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/500gb/database/cache': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/500gb/database/cache/cacheExt.xml': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/500gb/database/cache/media.xml': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/500gb/database/cache/cacheExtSchema_1.1.xsb': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/500gb/database/media': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/500gb/database/media/Stevenson-TreasureIsland.txt': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/500gb/database/media/Rendell-WolftotheSlaughter.txt': Operation not permitted

This process did the trick for me, thanks to Miroslav Koskar
/home/g # mount | grep sdb
/home/g # mount /dev/sdb -o uid=1000,gid=100 /500gb
/home/g # mount | grep sdb
/dev/sdb on /500gb type vfat (rw,uid=1000,gid=100)
/home/g # ls -l /500gb/database
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 g users 8192 Aug 10 11:23 cache
drwxr-xr-x 3 g users 8192 Aug  5 13:26 layout
drwxr-xr-x 2 g users 8192 Aug 10 12:51 media
drwxr-xr-x 2 g users 8192 Aug  5 17:28 sync
/home/g #
~ $ cp /home/g/MyBooks/Wyndham-TheMidwichCuckoos.txt /500gb/database/media
~ $

Comment: Did you see [this](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/slackware-linux/180294-writing-ntfs.html)? It probably has something to do with your problem

Comment: Sorry I should have given the additional info (para 2) that I have just added to the original post.  I can write to it as root, and its permissions, ownership etc are identical to other ntfs devices to which I can write as user

Comment: Mount the ereader and one of your “other NTFS file systems”, type `mount`, and post the output from that.  Also, please verify that, on the other devices, you (as a non-root user) can create new files in directories that are owned by `root` ***and are mode 755 (`rwxr-xr-x`)***.

Comment: Added to end of original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that permissions are not correctly set.

1. you are user `g` and can read a file = OK
2. but you can't create a file in a destination because the directory `media` is not writeable by you, only `root` can do that

So either copy as `root` or change the permissions on target so that you have a write permission on `media` directory.

---

As pointed out it's not possible to change permissions nor ownership on mounted NTFS filesystem. In that case there is a possibility to use proper mount options. Bellow excerpt from `man mount`

> uid=value, gid=value and umask=value

Set the file permission on the filesystem.  The umask value is given in octal. By default, the files are owned by root and not readable by somebody else.

---

Example: (for `/dev/sdc1` with FAT32 filesystem)

Check that the device is not mounted (following should return without output)

```
$ mount | grep sdc1
```

Mount the device with `uid` and `gid` option set

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 -o uid=1000,gid=1000 /mnt
```

Verify the mountpoint

```
$ mount | grep sdc1

/dev/sdc1 on /mnt type vfat (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

Comment: You cannot change the ownership or group of ntfs file systems, they are always root:root.  As far as I am aware, the first triad of permissions shown by ls -l refers to the current user (in this case myself, g), the second triad to all other users in the same group, and the third triad is to all other groups, so I have write permission to this device.

Comment: Well, the first triad is **not** for current user but for **owner**. So you don't have a correct permissions and that's the problem. For NTFS, right it might be a problem that you can't change the permission while mounted. In that case I think you can specify ownership by some mount option.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct.  Not only that, the ereader is fat32 rather than ntfs as I had assumed,  and the problem seems to be that I cannot change its permissions at all, neither as root nor as user.  See additional info added at end of original post

Comment: Maybe you should set mount options as pointed out in my answer, they are the same for NTFS and FAT like filesystems.

Comment: Like this?  /home/g # mount -t vfat -O uid=1000,gid=100,umask=0755 /dev/sdb /500gb  
/home/g # ls -l /500gb/database  
total 32  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug 10 11:23 cache  
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 8192 Aug  5 13:26 layout  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug 10 12:51 media  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug  5 17:28 sync  
/home/g # chmod -R 777 /500gb/database  
/home/g # ls -l /500gb/database  
total 32  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug 10 11:23 cache  
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 8192 Aug  5 13:26 layout  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug 10 12:51 media  
Its the same as before

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example. I've tried this myself and it works like expected.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem, for it changed the ownership to g:users, and the cp as user worked fine, but I posted it at the end of my original post, as I can't seem to get new-lines in these comment boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The `media` directory is owned by `root` (with a group of `root`) and is mode 755, so it is writable only by its owner (`root`).  You’re trying to create a file in that directory (you’re not overwriting an existing file, are you?) which is treated as a modification of the directory.  And you’re not running as `root`. 
That’s probably why you don’t have permission.

Either `chown` the `media` directory to yourself (or `chmod` it so you can write to it), or run the `cp` under `su` or `sudo`.

Comment: Here is the result of chown on /500gb.  As you see it makes no difference to the existing setup  /home/g # chmod 777 -R /500gb
/home/g # ls -l /500gb/database/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug 10 11:23 cache
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 8192 Aug  5 13:26 layout
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug  9 14:07 media
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8192 Aug  5 17:28 sync
/home/g # ls -l /500gb          
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 8192 Aug  5 17:28 database
/home/g #